# Angular Generate Pure HTML from Module JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Сan't generate an pure HTML file from current JSON data.

I tried to generate pure HTML file from angular generated module JSON:

```
{"surveyTitle":"ddasdas","surveyType":"Training","surveyQuestions":[{"questionTitle":"dasda","questionType":"Single choice","questionGroup":{"options":[{"optionText":"dsadsa"},{"optionText":"dasdsa"}],"showRemarksBox":false}}],"IsAnonymous":false}
```

To solve it I used this source below

from here [surveyjs.io](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=questiontype-radiogroup&platform=jQuery&theme=modern#content-js) :

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>One choice - Radio Group question, jQuery Survey Library Example</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/survey-jquery@1.8.75/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/survey-core@1.8.75/modern.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"></head>
    <body>
        <div id="surveyElement" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"></div>
        <div id="surveyResult"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
Survey
    .StylesManager
    .applyTheme("modern");

var json = {
    questions: [
        {
            "type": "radiogroup",
            "name": "car",
            "title": "What car are you driving?",
            "isRequired": true,
            "hasNone": true,
            "colCount": 4,
            "choices": [
                "Ford",
                "Vauxhall",
                "Volkswagen",
                "Nissan",
                "Audi",
                "Mercedes-Benz",
                "BMW",
                "Peugeot",
                "Toyota",
                "Citroen"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (sender) {
        document
            .querySelector('#surveyResult')
            .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3);
    });

$("#surveyElement").Survey({model: survey});
```

But I getting errors for my current JSON.

My Code Here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-survey-creation-swcerm?fbclid=IwAR1zR-5xxjjeD38wdhFzy7eKEFOiUAFbHNDhP-tarNxMICkRQPe-fCay0os&file=src%2Fapp%2Fcreate-survey%2Fcreate-survey.component.ts) - by clicking Add New Survey JSON has generates.

Comment: You will need to write some code that converts the object `surveyForm.value` into the format expected by surveyjs. Their structures are very different. You can't really expect to feed the former into surveyjs directly.

Comment: Yes, I was planning to do it. But was curious for some another workaround ... Do you have any source for this?

Comment: This might be of some use: https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs_angular_cli

Comment: Thanks for that, could you please apply for this question, I'll mark your answer as  Solution? :)

Comment: I honestly don't think this would qualifiy as a full-blown answer, but if you want to give some credit, just mark my comment as useful.